# How to generate value by first npm script and pass it dynamically to second npm script

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io, inquirerjs

I am trying to create something like custom launcher for my testing framework using  inquirer.js. I want to run inquirer by npm script and select values from list and on the end generate url and pass this url to my test which is run by second npm script. Anybody know how do it? Now I always have undifinde value in url, so probbaly it means that after generated url first npm script is end. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs API provide `process.stdin` & `process.stdout` which allow piping data from a process to another.

The article [Working with stdout and stdin of a child process in Node.js](http://2ality.com/2018/05/child-process-streams.html) may explain all the required knowledge you need.